# how to append data to a list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, append

i m trying to get buy signals by using stockstats macdh values.I can get macdh values and when i print them i can see values. but when i use if status for getting buy signals my buy signals list is empty. there might be something wrong with macdh values type. how can fill buy signals list?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from stockstats import StockDataFrame as Sdf



class TradingModel:
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.df = self.getData

    @property
    def getData(self):
        base = 'https://api.binance.com'
        endpoint = '/api/v3/klines'
        params = '?&symbol='+self.symbol+'&interval=4h'

        url = base + endpoint + params


        Data = requests.get(url)
        dictionary = Data.json()


        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
        df = df.drop(range(6, 12), axis=1)


        # rename columns and stockstasts
        col_names = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
        df.columns = col_names
        stock = Sdf.retype(df)

        for col in col_names:
            df[col]=df[col].astype(float)

        df['macdh']=stock['macdh']

        return  (df)

    def strategy(self):
        df = self.df
        buy_signals=[]
        for i in range(1, len(df['close'])):
                if df['macdh'].iloc[-1]>0 and df['macdh'].iloc[-2]<0:
                    buy_signals.append([df['time'][i], df['low'][i]])
                print(buy_signals)
def Main():
    symbol = "BTCUSDT"
    model = TradingModel(symbol)
    model.strategy()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers need good questions. Have a look at [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can edit your questions to make it easier to get help.

Comment: @run-out hi there i ve edited last place of code. i ll read them thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

On running your code I observed that the values for both `df['macdh'].iloc[-1]` and `df['macdh'].iloc[-2]` are negative together in all cases so the condition `if df['macdh'].iloc[-1]>0 and df['macdh'].iloc[-2]<0` is never satisfied, but the code for appending the list is correct and will work once the condition is satisfied.

Hope it helps!